# Example Context free grammar

Tags: formal-languages, context-free, formal-grammars

Is there a nice way to give context free grammar for
$$\{a^nb^ma^kb^l:n+m=k+l\}?$$

From PDA point of view it seems we just push + on stack if we see a, push + on stack if we see b, pop + from stack if we see a, pop + from stack if we see b and accept if you have empty stack.

Comment: Every decent automata theory textbook gives a description of how to convert a PDA to a CFG.  So, simply apply that construction and you'll get a CFG for that language.  There's little point in us repeating the description that construction here, and a question that says "please run standard algorithm X on my particular input Y for me" seems of unclear value (to me) -- better for you to run it yourself.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a simple grammar:
$$
\begin{align*}
& S \to aSb|U|V \\
& U \to aUa|T \\
& V \to bVb|T \\
& T \to bTa|\epsilon
\end{align*}
$$

Comment: And why would that be correct?

Comment: Just a feeling. The OP didn't ask for a proof, just for a grammar.

Comment: Of course it is indeed correct. Very nice job, Yuval.

Comment: Looks like something Arul can use to practice structural induction on.

Comment: no I am just looking for a verbatim way to see if PDA has a canonical transfer to CFG

Comment: @Arul There is an algorithm for converting PDA to CFG. You could run it.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus it seems very intuitive to think of pads rather than cfgs I don't know why this is

Comment: Also is there a notion of non-ambiguous PDAs?