# What's the Context-Free grammar of this language : $L= \{a^n b^m c^p d^q |m+n=p+q, n,m,p,q \geq0 \}$

Tags: context-free, formal-grammars

I was trying to find the context-free grammar of
`$L= \{a^n b^m c^p d^q |m+n=p+q, n,m,p,q \geq0 \}$ but I'm stuck.
This is what I did so far:

$$ S  \to X S Y | \lambda$$
$$X \to a|b$$
$$Y \to c|d
$$
but I figured out that it doesn't respect the order.
My Question is different from [this one](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/83150/is-this-language-context-free-l-ambncpdq-mn-pq+) because here $n, m, p or q$ can be equal to $0$ which is not the case in the other question where the answer use $a, d >0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can "force" the order using the following "trick":

- $S\rightarrow aSd \mid X \mid Y$
- $X\rightarrow bXd \mid Z$
- $Y \rightarrow aYc \mid Z$
- $Z \rightarrow bZc \mid \epsilon$

Basically, we allow $S$ to only derive $a$'s and $d$'s (the "outer" part of a fully derived word). Then, we allow $S$ to derive either $X$ or $Y$, each of them representing a change: we start to write $b$'s instead of $a$'s or start using $c$'s instead of $d$'s (this is the second-innermost part of a fully derived word), and finally $Z$ allows only $b$'s and $c$'s (which is the innermost part of a fully derived word)

Comment: Thank you for your help :)